# Finding the pressure in a sound wave in air

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, pressure, acoustics

My question stems from the following exercise:

[image]

The pressure of this sound wave, from what I've calculated, is around ten thousand times less than that of ambient pressure of air. I'll take you through what was going on in my head:

- For (c), I can find the wave number and wavelength by noting that the speed of sound in air is roughly $343 \ m/s$ and using $v = \frac{\omega}{k}$ to determine $k = 3000/343$.
- This leaves me to have a pressure expression of $$\frac{\partial s(x,t)}{\partial x} = (3000/343)(6\ nm)\ \cos \ ((3000/343)x+3000s^{-1}t)$$

$$\implies p = -B \left((-5.2 * 10^{-8})\ \cos \ ((3000/343)x+3000s^{-1}t)\right)$$

With pressure $p_m = 7.384 * 10^{-3} kPa$ assuming a bulk modulus of $B = 1.42 * 10^5 Nm^{-2}$

This is an enormous amount less than atmospheric pressure. This could *possibly* be okay, given that the amplitude of longitudinal oscillation being at a scale of nanometers, but if I were to guess, I may have made a mistake in calculating the wave number. Is this thought process reasonable?

Comment: In your equation for speed of sound $v=\sqrt{B/p}$ the variable $p$ (pressure) should be $\rho$ (density).

Comment: Foolish me! I'll edit out all of that, but then my main question is if my answer to (e) is reasonable.

Comment: That is something you could easily google, isn't it? eg wikipedia on [sound pressure level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure#Sound_pressure_level)